# Netbeans: Automatically Select Current File in Projects

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-6.9

How can I get Netbeans to automatically select (highlight) the currernt file in the Project window? Whenever I select a file in an editor tab I would like the project window to move to that file (expand parent packages/directories if necessary).

At work it has always done this but at home it does not. I figure there is a configuration option somewhere but I can't find it. I run the same version at home as at work (6.9) the only differences being I use Windows at work and Linux at home and my Netbeans install at work was upgraded from 6.8 while my 6.9 install at home is fresh.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Try `View` → `Synchronize Editor with Views` (it should be selected)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this tip! I have been looking for that setting for months. To be honest, I think they should reformulate the text to be consistent with the text shown when you click on the file tab where it says "Select in projects". Two formulations which are widely apart.

Comment: This should make more sense somewhere in the Panel (as a right-button or so) itself.

Comment: Thanks, I needed it the other way round (not sync with Projects), but it helped anyway.